# Using wireshark to monitor certain requests from another server

Tags: java, bash, networking, wireshark

I have looked around and tried a a lot of solutions and none have worked for me.

I have a remote server running a java application. This application makes API calls. All I want to do is see the requests that the java application is making to this API.

I have done followed instructions in https://serverfault.com/questions/362529/how-can-i-sniff-the-traffic-of-remote-machine-with-wireshark

My slightly edited instructions look something like

```
mkfifo /tmp/somename

wireshark -k -i /tmp/somename

ssh someuser@someip "tcpdump -s 0 -U -n -w - -i en0 port applicationport" > /tmp/somename
```

Of all the packets I am seeing my remote server's ip address doesn't appear as the source in any of them.

All I want to do is be able to confirm that requests are being sent from this java application to this API. The number of requests would also be useful.

Comment: If the API is running on a `https` link, you will not be able to log any requests or responses. This is because a secure tunnel is established between client and server and every man in the middle would just see the encrypted data which does not make any sense to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the request going out on another interface.
Try:

```
ssh someuser@someip "tcpdump -s 0 -U -n -w - -i any port applicationport" > /tmp/somename
```